# Rails nested, complex form for image gallery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to create a media gallery in my Rails application.

I have two models, Album and Image. Stripped versions below:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :albums

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Since an Image can belong to many Albums and an Album can have many Images, I suspect they should both have `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Can someone confirm this is correct? Associations still puzzle me quite often.

For the gallery, I'm using the `albums#index` page to list all albums. A button on the page lets the user create an album and redirects to this album's `#show` method. And that's where I'm stuck.

From a UX point of view, I don't want to force my users to create an album, then go to a separate page to upload images into that album. I want them to be able to upload  images on the album#show page.

I had something like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @album], html: { multipart: true } do |a|
  = a.simple_fields_for :images do |i| 
    = i.input :title
    = i.file_field :image
  = a.submit
```

This doesn't work. I get an error saying: `Image(#70146236626460) expected, got Array(#70146232389660)`

I then tried rendering a template from the ImagesController in my album#index view:

`= render admin/images/form`

I'm using the `inherited_resources` gem, so in my AlbumController I did:

```
def show
  super do
    @image = Image.new
  end
end
```

Which solved the first error I got, but then it gave me more errors and I decided that this could not be the correct way to go about it.

So.. tl;dr: simple question. How do I get a form to upload an image and associate it with the correct album on the `album#show` page?